# Connecting through Google Hangout button on a website

Tags: google-hangouts

I have added a hangout button on my website.

My question is:

Can two or more person may connect each other by google+ hangout without sending invitation to each other?

Can there be a default Id or account to which people will connect whenever they will click on hangout button without inviting people?

If two persons on different location click on the hangout button on my site they  should get connected to each other without inviting each other but this is not happening. On both screen on hangout this message is showing :"You are alone here" join.

How can I connect them on hangout without invitation because they do not know who else is available ?

please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

you could write a hangout app to fetch the hangout url. Attach the app with hangout button.  So when the first user starts a hangout , fetch the url and replace the button with a link to the url. On clicking the url,one will be redirected to the hangout started by the first user.

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Al4SbeVyLm4
```

The above video demonstrates how to write a hangout app and to fetch the hangout url.